# Android YouTube API YouTubePlayer does not work as expected when calling multiple functions in sequence

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

The following code gets the video cued but it does not play it. However, it does play it if I am debugging it. Am I missing something here?

```
player?.cueVideo("D7SlGMif9hw")
player?.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess not. Youtube API is kind of buggy. I had some issues regarding this. Some features work fine in debugging mode in my Android Studio IDE, but on regular play does not work.

To play videos just use `.loadVideo(string)`